# PC turning on and off

Tags: cpu, motherboard, power-supply, shutdown

Yesterday I built my PC. I have done it for the first time. But when I switched it on, it turned on for about 30 seconds and then turned off. It kept repeating the cycle infinitely.

So then I tried to remove all the components but the CPU and system fans from the motherboard but the problem still persisted. I have no idea what to do and this was my first time building a pc.

The parts of the pc are listed as:

Gigabyte b150m D3h MOBO

i5 6500

zotac 1060 mini 6gb

corsair vengenace lpx 8gb ram

Antec VP 450W PSU

Other things to note that I connected the monitor to motherboard not graphics card. I also wasted some thermal paste  touching the backside of CPU fan with my hand for I am a noob on building a pc and did not handled it properly :/. I checked the pins on the motehrboard and they appear to be fine. I dont know the problem. Please help

Comment: Do you hear it beep while booting up?  How many times? The m/b manual should have a troubleshooting section that details possible errors.

Comment: @mcalex I hear no beeps. I think my motheboard do not has the motherboard speaker

Comment: @SarangKhajuria Can you post a photo of how the system is connected, so a Photo of the motherboard with the power supply plugged in and nothing else.

Comment: @RyanIG I ma at office at the moment. I will do once i reach home.

Comment: Remove the Motherboard from the cabinet and connect only power supply and display. Then try to go to bios page and check.

Comment: @vembutech I have already tried connecting only the motherboard to power supply without processor and any other connector and it shuts down in 10 seconds.

Comment: Your Motherboard is new or old one. Have you noticed any capacitor bulge at top.

Comment: It  is a new one. I have not noticed any capacitor bulge at the top

Comment: @vembutech I will try with the display though in the evening when I reach home

Comment: Issue solved? or still facing same issue. Have you checked the motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

Take the CPU out and look at the pins in the socket with a magnifying glass. Chance are that one or more are bent.

Comment: I checked. The pins look fine to me

Answer (score 0):

If you had it down to just the motherboard (no CPU) and the power supply that narrows it down to two things. Either the power supply or the motherboard.

If you had no memory and no processor then it should have given you beep codes. The fact that there were no beep codes would point to a faulty motherboard.

Comment: I didn't have a motherboard speaker to give beeps. Anyways I have replaced my motherboard last night and I'll try again today to see if it works.